# How to loop through a WordPress WP_Query object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm passing a `WP_Query` object to a success function in my JavaScript file and am having problems trying to loop through it.

My PHP:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Pass the $query object to the success function in my script.
echo json_encode( $query );
```

My success function in my script:

```
success: function( data ) {
    // I'd like to loop through the query object here.
},...
```

I know how to loop through a WP_Query object server-side:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
    }
}
```

But how can I loop through the query object using jQuery inside my success function in my script?

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating over it like so:

```
for(var i in data) {
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(data[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: No worries. Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to use getJSON function in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ and loops through like any other javascript variable.

eg.

```
for (var object in data) {
  ....do stuff
}
```

Comment: Getting the object isn't the problem. Inside my success function `data` will hold the object. My problem is looping through. I'm fine with PHP but am new to jQuery

Comment: @henrywright yes but it is important what you do with that return, getJSON will decode the JSON string creating an object. That is not always the case using the jQuery.ajax.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the tip, I'll look into decoding the string

Answer (score 1):

I question whether you want the entire WP_Query object returned, or just the results of the query (the posts property).  My suggested approach would be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Pass the $query object to the success function in my script.
echo json_encode( $query->posts );
```

... and in the jQuery:

```
success: function( data ) {
    for(var i in data) {
        var post = data[i];
        // Do something with post object here...
    }
},...
```

Comment: Thanks for this example, Justin. Regarding the `post` object, say I wanted to access the post title property, would I do that like this `post.post_title`? Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Comment: Yes, this is a serialized version of the $post object from WordPress.  You will not receive some of the benefits of native WP functionality, such as the way get_content() wraps paragraphs or get_permalink() generates links, but you will get the object as it is represented in the database.